# What is the correct usage of the term "snafu"?

Tags: usage

If I want to convey that "this update has caused a lot of confusion", then what should I say? I understand that this term is a bit informal, nonetheless I would like to use it in my sentence.

Comment: "Snafu" originated in U.S.  military jargon as an initialism of the phrase _"Situation Normal: All Fucked Up."_ However, the verb was soon bowdlerized to _fouled,_ and _snafu_ is now an acceptable, if somewhat informal, noun. _"The update caused some snafus"_ is informal and will be understood by most English speakers.

Comment: As @PEDant said, the word *snafu* is understood my **most** English people, but not all, so I personally would exercise caution when using it

Comment: I doubt that **most** English people would understand snafu. Among the the engineering and IT fraternity this might be the case, but not the wider community. I see no benefit to using the term in preference to more standard words such as **problems** or **issues**. In addition to the question of whether you will be understood by your audience, you are using a term that implies it is **normal** to create problems - cynically, this is probably the case but let's not appear to be accepting of failure!

Comment: [Given that the use of "snafu" keeps increasing](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=snafu&year_start=1930&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csnafu%3B%2Cc0), I'd expect it to be understood by most American English speakers.  I can't address how common it is in Commonwealth English or Indian English or elsewhere.

Comment: "Snafu" is the name of a [children's board game](http://www.darwinsgamecloset.com/snafu1995.html), for what it's worth.

Comment: @P.E.Dant "All fouled up" for polite circles

Comment: @Andrey Are you familiar with the verb _to bowdlerize?_

Answer (score 1):

"This update has been a total snafu."

I am assuming you mean the update was badly done, not that other things went wrong AFTER the update was carried out.